# How to extract specific number from a cell in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to extract a specific number from a string of text in a cell and then paste it in another cell.

For example:
My cell has a string of text resembling the following: "Conflict 270 civil and drainage plans 70 %"

The percentages vary between 30%, 70%, 100%

Id like the percentage to appear in alone in a specific cell.

I tried using =IFS and nesting a MATCH function but had no luck.

Does anyone know how to detect the percentage and paste it in a cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try below formula:

```
   =value(regexextract(A1,"\S+%"))
```

and then change the cell format to %

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This seems like it would work! does it work if there is text after the 70%?

Comment: I tweaked your formula because it wasnt working. im now doing =value(regexextract(A1,"\d+\s\%")). It detects the number with the percent symbol but its giving me a parsing error. Do you know how to get around that? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the string you have, please share a sample of your string/text or share google sheet.